# Unable to start mysql on MacOS

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to set up MySQL on my MacBook Pro, OS Monterey. When I press "Start MySQL Server" in System Preferences, it turns on, and then back off again. Sometimes it will stay on (after uninstalling, restarting my computer, and reinstalling), however when I try mysql -u root -p in terminal, or logging in on MySQL Workbench with the password I set during install, it says Access Denied. When I try to initialize a database, I get this error:

```
2022-08-17T13:58:03.594154Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/local/mysql-8.0.30-macos12-arm64/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) initializing of server in progress as process 1279
2022-08-17T13:58:03.596412Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql-8.0.30-macos12-arm64/data/ is case insensitive
2022-08-17T13:58:03.604502Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-08-17T13:58:03.721094Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-08-17T13:58:05.536330Z 5 [Note] [MY-010454] [Server] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: W<dvfErrh0DC
2022-08-17T13:58:06.411738Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.30).
2022-08-17T13:58:07.176536Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/mysql-8.0.30-macos12-arm64/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 1284
2022-08-17T13:58:07.179562Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql-8.0.30-macos12-arm64/data/ is case insensitive
2022-08-17T13:58:07.194523Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-08-17T13:58:07.269541Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-08-17T13:58:07.400561Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011300] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Setup of socket: '/tmp/mysqlx.sock' failed, can't open lock file /tmp/mysqlx.sock.lock'
2022-08-17T13:58:07.498398Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2022-08-17T13:58:07.498450Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2022-08-17T13:58:07.499048Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010262] [Server] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
2022-08-17T13:58:07.499068Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010257] [Server] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2022-08-17T13:58:07.499087Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-08-17T13:58:08.543591Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/mysql-8.0.30-macos12-arm64/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

I'm not really sure what to do at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

To summarize, in System Preferences when I press "Start MySQL Server", it turns on for a few seconds and then turns off again. That is my first issue. The second problem is that if it stays on, I can't log in. I've tried both on the command line and using MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Someone else had this exact problem earlier, and it turns out they were using MySQL workbench, which also uses port 3306. See if that's it

Comment: @BarryCarter can't even get the MySQL server to start in System Preferences. Once I made it to that step (after restarting and reinstalling MySQL). What port should I be using? I can't use 4300, that's being used by PHP.

Comment: @BarryCarter MySQL Workbench would use 3306 to talk to the mysql server (as it's just a client), but it wouldn't/shouldn't be listening on 3306, that wouldn't make much sense. I suspect port 3306 is in use because mysqld may already be running when OP runs whatever command kicked this off. Hard to guess though.

Comment: I wonder what `sudo lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN | grep :3306` says is listening on that port.

Comment: @JNevill Here's what comes up when I run that command: mysqld    1110     marcofusco   20u  IPv4 0xfd195c09338d0889      0t0    TCP localhost:3306 (LISTEN)

Comment: So you have a mysql daemon running on your machine that is listening on that port already. Trying to run a second mysqld is going to result in that error that popped since two instances can't listen to the same port. The real question is are you able to connect a client to that running instance?

Comment: @JNevill should I uninstall mysql daemon? I'm not sure how or where or what that is. I must have configured it awhile ago.

Comment: I would wonder why it's running. Is it from your recent installation and it's running automatically (likely) and then the question is what command you ran that caused this error. why is that trying to kick off another instance of mysqld? Perhaps that command isn't doing what you think it's doing or you want it to do. If you have a daemon/server running already because of your install then it's just a matter of connecting a client to it.

Comment: I'm guessing/assuming a bit here. I've never ran mysql in mac and definitely not in the whatever way it is that you have installed it. Ultimately you need one server/daemon (mysqld) running and you need to connect to it with a client. whatever path forward to that end goal makes sense to you, is a good path forward.

Comment: At any rate, this is just on the edge of what Stackoverflow can support. You may, as you dig deeper, want to take this over to dba.stackexchange.com instead. Likely there's folks over there that have more expertise in environment set up and server management than us code jockey's on Stackoverflow.

Comment: When I run mysql -u root -p while the server is stopped in preferences, it asks for a password so maybe there is something running in the background? I don't remember the password so that's another issue. How can I reset it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had installed MySQL previously with Homebrew and they were both trying to run on port 3306.